# Breaking/reducing water adhesion with an electric field

Tags: adhesion

Does anyone know if the presence of an electric field can help to reduce water adhesion to a surface?

Comment: related   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocapillarity

Answer (score -1):

On the question relating to breaking/reducing water adhesion with an electric field, I suspect, the answer is that magnetic fields can have an impact.

Support, here is a 2008 paper published in *Journal of Applied Physics*, [The surface tension of water under high magnetic fields](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2940128), to quote in part:

> The surface tension of water-air interface was measured by means of a surface-wave resonance method under magnetic field up to 10 T. It was found that the surface tension increased linearly with an increase in the square of the magnetic field.

Of note, background on the concept of surface tension, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), to quote:

> At liquid–air interfaces, surface tension results from the greater attraction of liquid molecules to each other (due to cohesion) than to the molecules in the air (due to adhesion).
> There are two primary mechanisms in play. One is an inward force on the surface molecules causing the liquid to contract.[1][2] Second is a tangential force parallel to the surface of the liquid.[2] The net effect is the liquid behaves as if its surface were covered with a stretched elastic membrane.

So, per the cited paper, surface tension increased linearly with the square of the magnetic field. Per Wikipedia, surface tension relates directly to cohesion, as opposed to adhesion.

As such, the question likely correct cites increased magnetic fields as reducing water's adhesion (as it apparently relates to promoting surface tension/cohesion).